# Bounds and whole numbers

Tags: c++, math, bounds

I'm going through Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++". I am on chapter 4, exercise 4.

The excercise is as follows:

> Write a program to play a numbers guessing game. The user thinks of a number between 1 and 100 and your program asks questions to figure out what the number is (e.g. "Is the number you are thinking of less than 50?"). Your program should be able to identify the number after asking no more than seven questions. Hint: Use the < and <= operators and if-else constructs.

Now that is great, and I've managed to implement that fine.

I'd thought I'd try and push myself and try and implement this using a loop and adjusting lower or upper bounds each time.

Here is my code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main( ){
  int count = 0;
  int lowerBound = 0;
  int upperBound = 100;
  string userInput = "";

  while ( lowerBound != upperBound ){
    // Increment count
    ++count;

    int halfRange = 0;

    // Make halfRange a while number, round up if any decimal portion.
    double range = ( upperBound - lowerBound ) / 2;

    int rangeDelta = range - (int)range;

    if ( rangeDelta != 0 )
      halfRange = (int)range + 1;
    else
      halfRange = range;

    cout << count <<": Is your number between " << lowerBound << " and " << lowerBound + halfRange << "? ";
    cin >> userInput;

    // Reset the bounds
    if ( userInput == "y" || userInput == "Y" )
      upperBound -= halfRange;
    else if ( userInput == "n" || userInput == "n" )
      lowerBound += halfRange;
    else {
      --count;
      cout << "Error! Answer could not be understood.";
    }
  }

  cout << "lowerBound: " << lowerBound << ", upperBound: " << upperBound << "\n\n";
  cout << "Your number is: " << lowerBound << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

The problem? Well, it occurs when it gets to numbers where there is a decimal portion and using integer division, which throws the decimal part away. If you use the number 48, the program guesses to 47 and 47.

Any clues to get me going? I think I'm quite close, but will appreciate some help.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: It sounds like it would be better as `int halfRange = std::ceil((upperBound - lowerBound) / 2.0);`. `ceil` takes a floating-point number and returns that rounded up. Alternatively, it looks like `std::rint` with a rounding style of always up would do the trick and return an integral type as well.

Comment: To be honest, I would get rid of floating-point math *entirely*.

Comment: @NPE, True, it's not nearly as bad to do so here as it could be.

Comment: Is the number to be guessed always an integer?

Comment: @Richard: I am pretty sure it is. The problem statement would not make a lot of sense if it wasn't.

Comment: The algorithm used here is binary search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is still an issue in your code (even if the bugs signaled before are fixed): it should be clear that **upperbound and lowerbound are both included** in possible numbers remaining and this is not clear from your code: at the first question, if I answer 'y', the new interval is [0,50] and if I answer 'n', the new interval is [50,100], which is wrong! 50 should not be included in the second interval.

To fix this, you should change the update of your bounds to something like:

```
if ( userInput == "y" || userInput == "Y" )
   upperBound = lowerBound + halfRange;
else if ( userInput == "n" || userInput == "n" )
   lowerBound = lowerBound + halfRange + 1;
```

Now there is still a problem with the last question, which remains the same forever. The problem is that when range=1, you have halfrange=1 as well and the question keeps the same.

To solve that issue, you should round **down** range. Just define it like:

```
int halfRange = ( upperBound - lowerBound ) / 2;
```

and now your code should work. Here is the code I would use for the while loop:

```
while ( lowerBound != upperBound ){
// Increment count
++count;

int halfRange = ( upperBound - lowerBound ) / 2;
int midpoint = lowerBound + halfRange;

cout << count <<": Is your number between " << lowerBound << " and " << midpoint << "? (both included) ";
cin >> userInput;

// Reset the bounds
if ( userInput == "y" || userInput == "Y" )
  upperBound = midpoint;
else if ( userInput == "n" || userInput == "n" )
  lowerBound = midpoint + 1;
else {
  --count;
  cout << "Error! Answer could not be understood.";
}
```

}

Remark that now we only use integers, no double at all! If you use integers, try to avoid passing by double, and use rather integer division and modulo to work with them (and do not use double to represent integers).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
 double range = ( upperBound - lowerBound ) / 2;
```

This line will give you problems since all the operands are `int` thus it is evaluated as an int instead as `double`. If this is not intentional, Change the `2` -> `2.0` to fix this issue.

```
int rangeDelta = range - (int)range;
```

Also are you sure you dont want `double rangeDelta`

Comment: Thanks, that's helped a bit. My problem still remains during the last questions to narrow the number down. I it is adding the halfRange to upperBound or lowerBound that is causing the problem

Comment: @SwiftlyDone I am not really sure.. maybe you could work it out on paper and see where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with arrays, which is explained by chapter 4.

```
int min = 1;    // range for our guessing game
int max = 10;
int guess = 0;  // value to keeep track of guessing
char choice = ' ';
vector<int>v;

// put all our values into a vector
for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    v.push_back(i);
}


while (v.size() != 1) {   // if there is only one value left, no guessing needed. jump out of loop

    guess = v[v.size()/2];   // find median

    cout << "\nIs your number less than " << guess << "? (y/n)\n";  // ask user for hint
    cin >> choice;

    if(choice == 'y') { //y: value is below median, pop values of median and above out of our range of values
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        v.pop_back();
    }
    else {  // n: value is median or above. erase the lower values out of our range of values
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            v.erase(v.begin());
        }
    }
} // end while
cout << "The number is " << v[0] << "\n";
```